# How to edit the state in react

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React and i am now facing the state management issue.

I wanna update the name of id = 2 to 'something edited'.

How can I edit only that id = 2? Someone help me pls.

This is my state.

```
let [items,setItems] = React.useState([
        {id:1, name:"aks"},
        {id:2, name:"acm"},
        {id:3, name:"hhn"}
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is an array, and you wanna edit only one of the elements. If you know that the element with id 2 will always be the second on the array, you can do it like this

```
const newArray = [...items];
newArray[1].name = "i've changed it";
setItems(newArray);
```

However, if you dont know the position, you can try this:

```
const newArray = [...items];
newArray.find(el => el.id === "2").name = "i've changed it";
setItems(newArray);
```

If you want to do it in a more elegant way, you could use the Array.prototype.map function like this

```
setItems(items.map(i => {
    return el.id === "2" ?
        { id: "2", text: "i've changed it" } : el;
}));
```

Comment: If you mark the answer as correct, then the next person looking for something like this can be more confident with the answer